# Length across cuboid at an angle

Tags: geometry, angle

I would like to calculate the change in length across a cuboid when looking at it from different angles (e.g. 10 and 20°).

In the illustration below the red arrows show the length I would like to calculate. Ideally, I would like to have an average of all the lengths across the cuboid. The aspect ratio between the width and length of the cuboid would be quite large (around 30).

[Illustration cuboid at different angles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3UcE.png)

---

[image]

---

What equation would you suggest?

Please do not hesitate if there is anything unclear.

Comment: (I added the image.)

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of the cuboid, it looks like this:

[image]

When the cuboid is rotated by some angle $\theta$, $\cos \theta = \frac{\text{adjacent side}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$, so the rotated length will be equal to $\cos \theta$ multiplied by the width of the cuboid.

Comment: Hi Toby, thanks for your reply and the helpful drawing. Just to clarify. Wouldn't it actually be the cos  = Adjacent / Hypotenuse in this case to calculate E->H in your drawing (what should correspond to the red arrows in my drawing)?

Comment: Thanks for the correction.